# Menu don't open in Clip-one Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using de layout framework called [Clip-one](http://themeforest.net/item/clipone-bootstrap-3-responsive-admin-template/5881143)

I put the html code of menu in a separate file, and i'm loading the menu on the end of index page.

The menu is loaded successfully, but the actions of this menu, like a click, doesn't work.

Every page needs to call an function called `Main.init()`. But seems like this function isn't called, because when i call her on chrome's console, the menu working.

This is my code at end of page:

```
<script>
        //Verifica o login do cara 
        var log = new cLogin();
        log.verificaLogin();

        //Faz o init 
        initIndexComponents();
        Main.init();
</script>
```

The function `initIndexComponents()` load the menu in the `box-menu` div

Just when a call again de `Main.init()` in console, the menu work.

Someone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using it inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/*Your code here*/

});
```

Comment: make sure your page does not have two ready functions. include all your functions in a single ready functions.

Comment: I'm loading the menu asynchronous, when the init of ClipOne was executed, the menu is not already loaded, now i change some configs and works fine.